# Background color not showing up?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to play with different colors to began a page that I need to create, however no colors are showing up? for the whole background it's just white..

HTML

```
 <div id="container">
    <h1>Test</h1>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

#container {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: #51445F;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/y92an/

Comment: [Works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/98wDn/). Check your console for errors: it could be how you linked the stylesheet.

Comment: I checked that, but I still just get white background..

Comment: Link us to a demo page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing i can think of that you didnt link the stylesheet to your HTML document.

Add this line of code to your HTML file:

```
<link href="linkToYourStyleSheet" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in the `head`section.

Also make sure your `container` `div` has actually a `id` of `container` and not a `class` by accident.

Comment: @user3697149 Your welcome :) Please accept my answer, so other people know this issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

can you add the whole code? maybe the problem is somewhere different?

actually, I can't find any errors in the code posted by you.